# UIView animations block is marked as escaping. Why?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

There is a clang noescape attribute for noescape closures in ObjC. [noescape attribute](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#noescape-clang-noescape-clang-noescape)

So why UIView animations block is not marked with it? This would lead to clearer code in swift

Right now it looks like this

`open class func animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval,... animations: @escaping () -> Swift.Void, completion: ((Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)`,

but it doesn't escape actually and called immediately.

Comment: In swift 3 onwards closures passed as an argument to functions are non escaping by default, I dont think specifying it explicitly would do much of a difference :) Lemme know if I misunderstood your question

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Why is the completion block not marked as escaping?

Comment: Because it's inside Optional, so it's already "escaped" to that Optional